# repetition of methods while purchasing

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

My control reaches to method:

```
IAPHelper.m
  - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
{
    switch (transaction.transactionState)
    {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            [self completeTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            [self failedTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

}
after notification method in

```
viewcontroller.m
- (void)productPurchased:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSLog(@"product purchased notification");
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];    

NSString *productIdentifier = (NSString *) notification.object;
NSLog(@"Purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
 }
```

how could i stop this ? any bunch line of code or something else that could stop going at transaction method in IAPHelper.m class after purchasing second product?

Comment: i am following ray wenderlich tutorial for in app and have to do functionality that is from 'requesting product identifier' to 'verification of receipt' on buy button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, i experienced similar behaviour some time ago. I managed to work around it by keeping track (locally) of already delivered products and i ignore the subsequent callbacks from StoreKit for the delivered products.

Comment: what should i do.. my notification methods are calling repeatedly .. without any reason. By the way, there is no need of notification methods but still at icon it have show how much user purchased a product. suggest me something or cn u provide ur local class code

Comment: i believe your `- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction` method is called repeatedly. So, save the ids of already purchased products locally (e.g. in plist or something) after you deliver your product for the first time & ignore future calls of the `- (void)completeTransaction`  for the products you have already delivered.

Comment: yup exactly method - (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction is calling repeatedly

Comment: i have saved in ids in nsuserdefault method.

Comment: no.. :( i have edited above.. my control still reaches to 'complete transaction method' and then to record transaction where i am verifying the receipt.

Comment: so, just use an if statement with two branches. One will go directly to the product delivery (if you have not saved the id for the product into your nsdefaults), otherwise you just confirm the product with storekit. hope that's clear.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4060/discussion-between-ketan-rajput-and-mja)